# Why Google Maps JavaScript API v3 returns different search result to search from maps.google.com

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am using google map javascript API v3 in my application.It returns different results from maps.google.com

Let me know why I am getting different search results.

Answer (score 2):

Certain data providers license their data to Google only for use on maps.google.com, not in the API. So that data can't be used by Google in the API. That is why the results are different.